# Signalling Game

Tags: game-theory, asymmetric-information, signaling

In the signaling game, we have two or more types that have distinct distribution.
I wonder did you come across any signaling game where the types have continuous distribution?
I am not sure whether that makes sense or not but I just wonder is there any research or reference available
Cheers,
Hamid

Comment: Sure, there are plenty. Just google "signalling games with continuous signals".

Comment: Thanks, That is great

Comment: https://economics.mit.edu/files/552 Page 5-7 of these notes has a nice continuous version of the classic Spence job market signaling game.